# Python Script Failure to add derived shapefile to current map document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-2.7, addlayer

I'm trying to do some work using Python 2.7 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 - I know old software.  For some reason that I cannot figure out, my script adds the derived featureclass / shapefile and then when the script finishes, the layer is no longer in my TOC. I've tried many of the suggestions I have found on the internet and nothing will make it stick.

```py
 # Accessing the current open ArcMap project.
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]    
    
    '''addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(PATH + os.sep + "sel_GVILandscapePolygon.shp")'''
    '''addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"E:\Junk\GVI_Query\sel_GVILandscapePolygon.shp")'''
    FnShp = PATH + os.sep + "sel_GVILandscapePolygon.shp"
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FnShp)
    
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP") 
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()       
    mxd.save()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I never quite found out why my derived output would not stay in my TOC; however, I did get it work by returning my input path variable to the root of the script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':


    # Return the Path variable from the main module.
    PATH = Main (arcpy)

    # Accessing the current open ArcMap project & dataframe.
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]    
    
    # Create a vaiable to provide the pathway to the shapefile that I want to add to my map.
    FnShp = PATH + os.sep + "sel_GVILandscapePolygon.shp"
    
    # Add the layer, refresh the TOC and save the mxd.
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FnShp)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP") 
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()       
    mxd.save()      

    # Clean up and terminate.
    del arcpy, mxd, df, FnShp, addLayer
    sys.exit(0)
```